# Hide a div when hovering over another div

Tags: css, hover, display

I've written CSS that should hide the container div in the middle of the page, when the list div on the left is hovered over. 
I've got a feeling that giving the container div a fixed position is causing this, but I'm not quite sure. The code seems correct.

Html

```
<section class="container"> 

  <div class="description">
    <h2>Writer</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suspendisse nam habitasse pellentesque arcu quae dignissim, amet magna diam aenean. Amet ipsum aenean, massa posuere maecenas nam lectus nibh lacus, nisl lacus magna nullam leo quis. Mi elit ante nunc, mi odio congue rhoncus dui quis dictum, lectus eleifend aliquam sed venenatis vitae lorem, potenti non dictum sit. Condimentum nonummy vitae tristique, pede nullam pretium arcu vestibulum dictum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suspendisse nam habitasse pellentesque arcu quae dignissim, amet magna diam aenean. Amet ipsum aenean, massa posuere maecenas nam lectus nibh lacus, nisl lacus magna nullam leo quis.</p>
  </div>

</section>

<div class="list">

 <ul class="projectList">
    <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
<div>
```

css

```
    .container {
  position:absolute;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:flex;
  width:500px;
  left:325px;
  align-content:space-around;
}

.list {
  width:325px;
  margin: 20px 30px 20px 0;
  box-sizing:bordr-box;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

.projectImage img {
  display:none;
}

.list .projectImage:hover img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  /* width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
}

.list:hover + section.container {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. Don't expect or force us to go to a third-party site to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.list:hover + section.container` would only work if `.list` would be the preceding sibling of `section.container`. But your `section.container` is placed before `.list`.

The only way to make it work is to place `.list` before `section.container`. To display `section` besides `.list`, I used `float: left;` on `.list`.

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmJZgm?editors=1100

**Note 1:** you might have to tweak the margins/paddings a bit.

**Note 2:** If you place any content after `section`, when hiding it the rest of the content will jump up. If you don't want this, you probably want to try

```
.list:hover + section.container {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I don't think I've be placing any content after section but I'll take note!

Answer (score 0):

If you move `.list` before `.container`, your selector will work. I added a parent element (`main`) to `.list` and `.container` and used `flex` on the parent instead of using `position: absolute` on `.container` to get it beside `.list`.

```css
#helene, body, html {
  width:100%
}

body {
  background-color:#FFFAF1;
}

#site {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}

.title {
  position:fixed:
  z-index:10;
  text-align:center;
}

.container {
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:flex;
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  align-content:space-around;
}

.list {
  flex: 0 0 325px;
  margin: 20px 30px 20px 0;
  box-sizing:bordr-box;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

.projectImage img {
  display:none;
}

.list .projectImage:hover img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  /* width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
}

.list:hover + section.container {
  display: none;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="helene">

  <div id="site">

    <header class="title">
      <h1> Helene Selam Kleih</h1>
    </header>


    <main>

      <div class="list">

        <h2>In Conversation With-</h2>
        <ul class="projectList">
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <h2>Articles - </h2>
        <ul class="projectList">
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="projectImage"><a href="#">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="" alt="" height="" width="" /></span></a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <section class="container">

        <div class="description">
          <h2>Writer</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suspendisse nam habitasse pellentesque arcu quae dignissim, amet magna diam aenean. Amet ipsum aenean, massa posuere maecenas nam lectus nibh lacus, nisl lacus magna nullam leo quis. Mi elit ante nunc, mi odio congue
            rhoncus dui quis dictum, lectus eleifend aliquam sed venenatis vitae lorem, potenti non dictum sit. Condimentum nonummy vitae tristique, pede nullam pretium arcu vestibulum dictum</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suspendisse nam habitasse pellentesque arcu quae dignissim, amet magna diam aenean. Amet ipsum aenean, massa posuere maecenas nam lectus nibh lacus, nisl lacus magna nullam leo quis.</p>
        </div>

      </section>

    </main>

  </div>

</div>
```